# Java Reflection - Get value of a field within nested classes

Tags: java

I want to retrieve value of a instance variable "customerId". I have a set of apis that return this field. In some of the apis , this field under the base class. In some cases , it is nested several levels below. Is there a way to fetch the value by field name "customerId" irrespective of where the instance variable is?

**Eg:**

```
Customer
   customerId

Order
 Customer
   customerId

Account
 Order
   customerId
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static Map<Field, Integer> getFieldWithName(Object o, Map<Field, Integer> list) throws IllegalAccessException {
    Class<?> c = o.getClass();
    for(Field field : c.getDeclaredFields()) {
        if(field.getName().equals("customerId") && field.getType().equals(int.class)) {
            list.put(field, field.getInt(o));
        } else {
            if(!field.isAccessible()) {
                field.setAccessible(true);
            }
            getFieldWithName(field.get(o), list);
        }

    }
    return list;
}
```

This will return a Map with the fields named customerId and the value stored in this field. Gl!

Comment: Be aware, that in the case of a circular reference presence, this code will produce an exception, after which this site is named. Also it won't handle the case when `customerId` is declared in a super-class of `o`. And it is prone to `NullPointerException`.